# Disable Google Analytics from a specific component of my React web app

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

I am creating my web app in React Js and I have implemented Google analytics, but now I want that when a specific component gets rendered to the browser then the google analytics should be disabled only for that component not from the entire web app.

Comment: so make that component not call any google analytics methods?

Comment: my app is calling ga methods not my components

Comment: well tour question is really not clear about what is happening. how does google analytics get called for this one component?

Comment: i have inserted my ga method directly into my index.html but i want analytics.js not to be executed when a specific components gets rendered

Comment: ok so just override it and make it null when you render a component. and then put it back when you unmount it